# How to implement nested composite types with pgx/pgtype

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx, pgx

To avoid complex 1-to-1 mappings between Postgres tables, I thought it would be a good idea to use composite types instead. So I created these two types, and a table to hold them:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_point AS (x INTEGER, y INTEGER);
CREATE TYPE my_rectangle AS (p1 my_point, p2 my_point);
CREATE TABLE zoo (id INTEGER, r my_rectangle, p my_point);
```

*(The types and tables are just for the example. In the real project, they are quite different, so there's no point in proposing alternative solutions, such as using the built-in Postgres `point` type)*

So far so good. It works as expected when doing manual queries in `psql` etc. Now to the problem:

I'm trying to access these types using `go`, `pgx` and `sqlx`. For the `my_point` type, I got a working solution quite easily by mostly copying the `point` implementation from `pgtype`. But no such luck for the `my_rectangle` type. I've tried to come up with multiple solutions, but run into different problems with each. The error I get with the code below for example is:

> Unknown OID for model.MyPointType{Point:model.MyPoint{X:20, Y:21}, Status:0x2}

Here's my test function:

```golang
func TestCompositeTypes(t *testing.T) {
    // Setup database connection ...
    conn := ...
    ci := conn.ConnInfo()

    // Get OID for "my_point"
    var myPointOID uint32
    err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), `select 'my_point'::regtype::oid`).Scan(&myPointOID)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    // Get OID for "my_rectangle"
    var myRectangleOID uint32
    err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), `select 'my_rectangle'::regtype::oid`).Scan(&myRectangleOID)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    ci.RegisterDataType(pgtype.DataType{
        Value: &MyPointType{},
        Name: "my_point",
        OID: myPointOID,
    })

    ci.RegisterDataType(pgtype.DataType{
        Value: &MyRectangleType{},
        Name: "my_rectangle",
        OID: myRectangleOID,
    })

    p := MyPointType{
        Point:  MyPoint{50, 100},
        Status: pgtype.Present,
    }

    // This works!
    _, err = db.Connection.Exec(
        "INSERT INTO zoo (id, p) VALUES ($1, $2::my_point)",
        100,
        p
    )
    require.NoError(t, err)

    r := MyRectangleType{
        P1:     MyPointType{Point: MyPoint{20, 21}, Status: pgtype.Present},
        P2:     MyPointType{Point: MyPoint{30, 31}, Status: pgtype.Present},
        Status: pgtype.Present,
    }

    // This does *not* work! (see error above)
    _, err = db.Connection.Exec(
        "INSERT INTO zoo (id, r) VALUES ($1, $2::my_rectangle)",
        100,
        r
    )
    require.NoError(t, err)
}
```

Here's the implementation of `MyPoint`:

```golang
type MyPoint struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

type MyPointType struct {
    Point  MyPoint
    Status pgtype.Status
}

func (p *MyPointType) AssignTo(dst interface{}) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("cannot assign %v to %T", p, dst)
}

func (p MyPointType) Get() interface{} {
    switch p.Status {
    case pgtype.Present:
        return p
    case pgtype.Null:
        return nil
    default:
        return p.Status
    }
}

func parsePoint(src []byte) (*MyPointType, error) {
    if src == nil || bytes.Compare(src, []byte("null")) == 0 {
        return &MyPointType{Status: pgtype.Null}, nil
    }

    if len(src) < 5 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid length for my_point: %v", len(src))
    }

    if src[0] == '"' && src[len(src)-1] == '"' {
        src = src[1 : len(src)-1]
    }

    parts := strings.SplitN(string(src[1:len(src)-1]), ",", 2)
    if len(parts) < 2 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid format for my_point")
    }

    x, err := strconv.ParseInt(parts[0], 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    y, err := strconv.ParseInt(parts[1], 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &MyPointType{Point: MyPoint{int(x), int(y)}, Status: pgtype.Present}, nil
}

func (p *MyPointType) Set(src interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        p.Status = pgtype.Null
        return nil
    }
    err := fmt.Errorf("cannot convert %v to MyPointType", src)
    var parsed *MyPointType
    switch value := src.(type) {
    case string:
        parsed, err = parsePoint([]byte(value))
    case []byte:
        parsed, err = parsePoint(value)
    default:
        return err
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *p = *parsed
    return nil
}

func (p MyPointType) EncodeBinary(ci *pgtype.ConnInfo, buf []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    switch p.Status {
    case pgtype.Null:
        return nil, nil
    case pgtype.Undefined:
        return nil, errUndefined
    }

    // This is how pgtype.Point does it, but I think my implementation below
    // works similarly and is more safe...?
    //
    // buf = pgio.AppendUint64(buf, math.Float64bits(src.P.X))
    // buf = pgio.AppendUint64(buf, math.Float64bits(src.P.Y))
    // return buf, nil

    return (pgtype.CompositeFields{int32(p.Point.X), int32(p.Point.Y)}).EncodeBinary(ci, buf)
}
```

And here's the implementation of `MyRectangleType`:

```golang
type MyRectangleType struct {
    P1     MyPointType
    P2     MyPointType
    Status pgtype.Status
}

func (r *MyRectangleType) AssignTo(dst interface{}) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("cannot assign %v to %T", r, dst)
}

func (r MyRectangleType) Get() interface{} {
    switch r.Status {
    case pgtype.Present:
        return r
    case pgtype.Null:
        return nil
    default:
        return r.Status
    }
}


func parseRectangle(src []byte) (*MyRectangleType, error) {
    if src == nil || bytes.Compare(src, []byte("null")) == 0 {
        return &MyRectangleType{Status: pgtype.Null}, nil
    }

    if len(src) < 5 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid length for my_rectangle: %v", len(src))
    }

    if src[0] == '"' && src[len(src)-1] == '"' {
        src = src[1 : len(src)-1]
    }

    parts := strings.SplitN(string(src[1:len(src)-1]), ",", 2)
    if len(parts) < 2 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid format for my_rectangle")
    }

    p1, err := parsePoint([]byte(parts[0]))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    p2, err := parsePoint([]byte(parts[1]))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &MyRectangleType{P1: *p1, P2: *p2, Status: pgtype.Present}, nil
}

func (r *MyRectangleType) Set(src interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        r.Status = pgtype.Null
        return nil
    }
    err := fmt.Errorf("cannot convert %v to MyRectangleType", src)
    var parsed *MyRectangleType
    switch value := src.(type) {
    case string:
        parsed, err = parseRectangle([]byte(value))
    case []byte:
        parsed, err = parseRectangle(value)
    default:
        return err
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *r = *parsed
    return nil
}

func (r MyRectangleType) EncodeBinary(ci *pgtype.ConnInfo, buf []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    switch r.Status {
    case pgtype.Null:
        return nil, nil
    case pgtype.Undefined:
        return nil, errUndefined
    }

    return (pgtype.CompositeFields{
        r.P1,
        r.P2,
    }).EncodeBinary(ci, buf)
}
```

What do I do wrong? What can be improved? I'm more concerned about readability than performance.

Comment: Have you tried `pgtype.CompositeFields{&r.P1, &r.P2}`?

Comment: I don't understand why this has a close vote. It is a good question IMHO and I would play with it if I had time :(

Comment: @mkopriva yes, same error:

`Unknown OID for &model.MyPointType{Point:model.MyPoint{X:20, Y:21}, Status:0x2}`

Comment: @Jonatan then perhaps try using [`CompositeType`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#CompositeType) instead of CompositeFields, since its own documentations explicitly recommends the use of CompositeType. => *"`EncodeBinary` encodes composite fields into the binary format. Unlike `CompositeType` the schema of the destination is **unknown**. Prefer registering a `CompositeType` to using `CompositeFields` to encode directly. Because the binary composite format requires the OID of each field to be specified the only types that will work are those known to ConnInfo."*

Comment: Do not use a composite type to represent a one-to-one mapping. Do not use a composite type in a column definition. Very likely, this is a sign of a bad schema design.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, this is not really related to my question, but would still love it if you could clarify why you think so. I think 1-to-1 (not 0..1-to-0..1) mappings are not handled great by SQL if you want to guarantee data consistency. The best way to handle that IMO is to just add more columns to the original table. However, in my case right now, I would need to add 21 columns! So by putting them in a composite type, I can instead add only one column. I'm quite happy with that schema design, so please tell me why you think it's bad.

Comment: The main reason: updating individual attributes of that composite value will be difficult. Also, indexing may be problematic. I see no advantage over adding 21 columns. If anything, use `jsonb` for those additional attributes. That doesn't make updating attributes any easier, but at least gains you the flexibility to add new columns on the fly, and you can index the whole thing with a single GIN index

Comment: I don't want flexibility, I want consistency, so I would strongly prefer to not use JSONB. And maybe I don't understand, but updating attributes is as easy as: `UPDATE zoo SET p.x=123 WHERE id=50`. I can imagine adding columns/fields being a problem, but not likely a need for my specific use case. No idea about indexing...